# A very simple local Java applet is not working in Java JRE 7 update 21

Tags: java

I have a Java applet that displays a simple image. I have the following HTML markup to run the applet:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Traffic Light Demo</title>
</head>
<body>
    <applet code="TrafficApplet.class" width="300" height="400">
    </applet>
</body>
</html>
```

The applet I am trying to run is in the same directory as this HTML file. It was running just fine until last weekend when I updated my JRE to update 21 (I also updated my JDK to the latest version at the same time.

I'm running a 64 bit Windows 7 system.

The problem I'm having is that when I try to run the HTML file I get an error that says:

> Application Blocked by Security Settings 
>   
>   Your security settings have blocked a local application from running.`

It was suggested to me that I try the following;
Open Control Panel, select Programs, select Java, select the Security tab, and move the slider to Medium (it defaults to High). I tried that. It had no effect. Also, when I close the Control Panel, try to re-run the HTML file, it fails, then try go back to the security setting, it has gone back to the High setting.

How do I fix this?

Comment: tried in other browsers?

Answer (score 0):

Most of the newer HTML5 documents have the

```
    !DOCTYPE html
```

heading, which the applet tag is now appreciated in HTML5. I am not sure as to how to load an applet, but when I tried an Applet in HTML5, it didn't support it. Also, the update might have caused the newer Java to conflict with whatever coding is in your applet.